My solution for $\lvert x-a\rvert<x-b$ disagrees with graphical evidence.
I am studying Introduction to Calculus and Analysis by Richard Courant, Section 1.1e, page 12, Question 1. (b).
The question: "Using signs of inequality alone (not using signs of absolute value) specify the values of $x$ which satisfy $\lvert x-a\rvert<x-b$."
I have a proposed solution, but can graph certain cases which do not fall within my solution. This gives me the impression that my approach must be wrong.
My Proposed Solution:
We know that $\lvert a-b\rvert$ is nonnegative, therefore $\lvert x-a\rvert<x-b$ implies that $x-b>0$, which is equivalent to $\boxed{x>b}$.
With that out of the way, we will split up the inequality using the relationship where $\lvert x\rvert<a\iff-a<x<a$.
$$\lvert x-a\rvert<x-b\iff\underbrace{(-(x-b)<x-a)}_{(A)}\land\underbrace{(x-a<x-b)}_{(B)}$$
Solving for (A), we get:
$$
\begin{aligned}
(A)&\iff-(x-b)<x-a)\\
&\iff x-b>a-x\\
&\iff2x>a+b\\
&\iff x<\frac{a+b}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$
And for (B),
$$
\begin{aligned}
(B)&\iff x-a<x-b\\
&\iff-a<-b\\
&\iff a>b
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $x>b$, and $x<\frac{a+b}{2}$, and $a>b$, I was able to come up with the interval in the following diagram:

An Apparent Problem With My Solution
The problem arises when I graph the functions. If $a<b$, then then $\lvert x-a\rvert$ is always greater than $x-b$, and if $a=b$ then they are the same, and (this is the important one) if $a>b$, then $x>\frac{a+b}{2}$
This means that $\lvert x-a\rvert<x-b$ is only true if $a>b$, and is the region $x\in\left(\frac{a+b}{2},\infty\right)$
The Contradiction
Clearly, $x\in\left(\frac{a+b}{2},\infty\right)$ is not the same as $x\in\left(b,\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$.
I trust the graphical evidence, so my impression is that my above reasoning must be incorrect. I am wondering where the gap in my foundation is.

When you rearranged (A) you made an error.

@Malady Thank you for letting me know of its existence and location. Would you mind elaborating on what the specific error is? I cannot identify it, even with the hint.

Here is the error:

$$
\begin{aligned}
(A)&\iff-(x-b)<x-a)\\
&\iff x-b>a-x\\
&\iff2x>a+b\\
&\iff x\color{red}{<}\frac{a+b}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Fixing this, it will give you the answer which the graphical analysis gave.
Hope this helps. :>

Ahh, I though I was reciprocating it there, but I'm just multiplying by one half!

The simplest way to split this up is into cases depending on whether $|x - a| = x - a$ or $-(x-a) = a-x$, i.e. how $x$ relates to $a$.
If $x \le a$, $|x - a| = a - x$ and your inequality says $a - x < x - b$, i.e.
$x > (a + b)/2$.  Note that $(a+b)/2 < x \le a$ implies $a > (a+b)/2$ and thus $a > b$.
If $x \ge a$, $|x - a| = x - a$, and your inequality says $x - a < x - b$, i.e. $a > b$.
So:

If $a \le b$, your inequality is never true.
If $a > b$, your inequality is true in both cases: $a \ge x > (a+b)/2$ and $x \ge a$, and thus $x \in ((a+b)/2, \infty)$.


Thank you. It took me a while to wrap my head around, but now I understand the concept better. If $x$ is less than $a$, then it is greater than the midpoint (and less than $a$), and if it is greater than $a$, then it is always greater than $a$. You put these two intervals together to account for both cases.
